# Несколько дивов в строку в одном li

Tags: css, html, ul

Есть `ul li`, в каждый `li` нужно помещать несколько дивов, выравнивая их в одну строку, про `float: left;` - знаю, но в данном случае это почему-то не сработало.

```css
#list_quest{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(41, 50, 81, 0.75);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
}

#ul_quests{
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.quest{
  width: 100%;
}

#q_count, #q_watcher, #q_date, #q_place{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="list_quest">
  <ul id="ul_quests">
    <li class="quest">
      <div id="q_count">1</div>
      <div id="q_date">27-08-2017</div>
      <div id="q_watcher">Иванова</div>
      <div id="q_place">
        <ul id="ul_places">
          <li>Лит 25</li>
          <li>Лит 6</li>
          <li>Лит 37</li>
          <li>Лит 38</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/g9b2yrh1/
Что не так?

Comment: Код добавлять лучше в тело вопроса.

Comment: думаю про float left вы не знаете... вы поставили для #q_count, #q_watcher, #q_date, #q_place  ширину на 100% как они могут вырвниватся в одну линию ?? вам или надо удалить 100% для дивов или же для родителя дивов поставить display:inline-flex;

Comment: Да, тут я глупо ошибся( Спасибо... А не подскажите еще, как весь `<ul id="ul_quests">` центрировать по горизонтали относительно `<div id="list_quest">`

Comment: Делайте что-то вроде: `#ul_places li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}` И при верстке лучше классы использовать.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#list_quest{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(41, 50, 81, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
}

#ul_quests{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.quest{
    width: 100%;
}

#q_count, #q_watcher, #q_date, #q_place{
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="list_quest">
  <ul id="ul_quests">
    <li class="quest">
      <div id="q_count">1</div>
      <div id="q_date">27-08-2017</div>
      <div id="q_watcher">Иванова</div>
      <div id="q_place">
        <ul id="ul_places">
          <li>Литке 25</li>
          <li>Литке 35</li>
          <li>Литке 36</li>
          <li>Литке 37</li>
          <li>Литке 38</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Как сказал @AndreyFedorov вы дали 100% `div`ам в этом случае свойство float работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

```
 лучшая штука для данного эффекта FLEX-сы
    #list_quest{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(41, 50, 81, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
}

#ul_quests{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.quest{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
     display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#q_count, #q_watcher, #q_date, #q_place{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```